# Does std::integral_constant<T, v>::value always have a definition?

Tags: c++, c++14

In the C++14 standard, the `std::integral_constant` template is defined as follows:

```
template <class T, T v>
struct integral_constant {
  static constexpr T value = v;
  typedef T value_type;
  typedef integral_constant<T,v> type;
  constexpr operator value_type() const noexcept { return value; }
  constexpr value_type operator()() const noexcept { return value; }
};
```

It doesn't say whether there's a corresponding out-of-line definition for the static data member, *i.e.*,

```
template <class T, T v>
constexpr T integral_constant<T, v>::value;
```

I looked through the standard for a requirement that such a definition be provided, but couldn't find one, so I don't know whether portable code may odr-use `value`.

(In C++17, `static constexpr` members became implicitly inline, making the in-class declaration a definition.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered by a blanket declaration in [[contents]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/contents#1) that defines the general rules for standard library implementations:

> The C++ standard library provides definitions for the following types of entities: macros, values, types, templates, classes, functions, objects.

Variables of non-reference types are objects, so `value` here is an object. Therefore, the standard library must provide a definition for it.

The [C++17 version of this statement](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/contents) is more direct on this matter:

> The C++ standard library provides definitions for the entities and macros described in the synopses of the C++ standard library headers.

`value` is most assuredly an entity, which is described in the synopsis of a C++ standard library header. Therefore, a definition must be provided.

Comment: Technically, the `integral_constant` template is mentioned in the synopsis of the corresponding header but its member `value` is not. I'm willing to believe that both of the quotations are intended to require `value` to be defined, but the wording isn't great.

Comment: @Brian: That kind of thinking leads to the belief that `vector::size` doesn't exist because it's not listed in [vector.syn](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/vector.syn). Since the `[.syn]` sections do not list *everything* in those headers, it stands to reason that later addendums that spell out specific types and their members should be considered part of the header's synopsis.

Answer (score 0):

According to [intro.compliance]/4,

> For functions, function templates, objects, and values, the library Clauses specify declarations. Implementations
>   shall supply definitions consistent with the descriptions in the library Clauses.

Since static data members are "objects", it appears that the standard requires all static data members of standard library classes to have definitions. (Exception: static data members of reference type are not "objects". I suppose they might be considered "values" and thus be required to have definitions as well. I also don't think there are any static members of reference type in the standard library, so this point is moot.)